# Clearing a collection with c# / asp.net model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to clear a collection with model bindning?

Sample model class:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public String Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public List<String> Strings
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Sample Html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="New name" />
    <input type="text" name="Strings[]" value="New str1" />
    <input type="text" name="Strings[]" value="New str2"/>
    <input type="text" name="Strings[]" value="New str3"/>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And controller code:

```
public IActionResult Post()
{
    var model = new TestModel() { Name = "Old name" };

    model.Strings = new List<String>();
    model.Strings.Add("Old str 1");
    model.Strings.Add("Old str 2");

    this.TryUpdateModelAsync(model);
}
```

In this case the TryUpdateModelAsync will update both Name and Strings but what if I would like to clear the list with TryUpdateModelAsync?

changing html to:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Name" valuye="New name" />
    <input type="text" name="Strings" value="" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

will of course update Strings to a list with one empty / null value and removing input for Strings will keep the old list intact (as expected), but is there any magic trick to just clear that list or set it to null?

Comment: Why would you want that? What is the reason a call to `List<string>.Clear()` in your action method or a filter won't work?

Comment: Please fix your tags about which framework this is for.

Comment: What does the cshtml look like? how exactly do you bind to the textboxes?

Comment: This is a  what I belive is a good enough "summary" of the problem. Why does it mather what I'm gonna use it for :) ? The cshtml is in the html sample...

Comment: @LennartStoop I'm not sure I understand your questioon, but the textboxes binding will happen in the controllers method: TryUpdateModelAsync()

Comment: Okej: Reason for not doing a manual clear or filter is a case where you don't know if the form collection will include data for the list or not, so the client needs the options to just leave the list as it is or clear it because it's empty. Understandable :) ? Compare it with the "hidden" model binding feature of "name=List.Index". I'm just wondering if there is a similar solution to this that I'm missing...

Comment: sorry are you trying to clear the records from the db or from the screen?  I think it's from the screen so I'll answer that way.